# Do handles on exterior steel doors need sealed from rain?

Tags: doors, exterior, hardware, rust-proofing, house

I have a storm door on my front door, but not on our new mudroom addition. Do I need to worry about rain water getting behind the handle and rusting the hole that was cut in the door?

Comment: Probably not that hole, but maybe the bottom of the door where water would collect.  Handles should be quite tight on the door and limit any water ingress, but if you want be seal it better a bit of silicon would not hurt.  Water will take the easiest way to go down, it will usually find it easier to go around a handle than go under a handle.

Comment: Is your door steel, or aluminum?

Comment: Steel material is the door

Answer (score 1):

Did you apply caulking to the trim ring, leaving a gap on the bottom of the trim ring (only)?

If yes, you should be fine. If no, do that, and then you should be fine.

Comment: Apply caulk on the outside of the trim ring or underneath somehow?

Comment: Normally underneath by doing it at installation time - or partially disassembling so you can do that. It's neater than just smearing it outside. Either will work if you don't mind the appearance of doing it on the outside.